# UITableView Editing Not working

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipopovercontroller, edit

I have a UITableView which lies in a NavigationController that is in a popover. So, I put an edit/done UIToolBarItem which works fine and you can see the delete accessory icon showing up. However, when I rearrange the items, the edit/done button stops working...

I debugged and it still gets called but it doesn't seem to update and is sort of preventing any further updates from other buttons. Is this possibly a problem with the simulator?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Edit: Adding code

```
addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered     target:self action:@selector(editTable:)];
```

And later on the method:

```
- (IBAction) editTable: (id) sender
{
    if ([[addButton title] isEqualToString:EDIT_STRING]) {
        [addButton setTitle:DONE_STRING]; //enabling edit mode  
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    }
    else {
        [addButton setTitle:EDIT_STRING]; //done with editing
        [[self tableView] setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [super setEditing:NO animated:YES];

        [[self tableView] setNeedsDisplay];
        [[self tableView] reloadData];  
    }
}
```

The second part is definitely called as the addButton text is changing. However, it stops working once I make an edit (such as re-arranging a row)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright,

I seemed to have called [tableView beginUpdates] and never called endUpdates, which was causing all updates to not be registered. If anyone else does that...

Comment: Wow. same mistake here. That was dumb of me. Thanks for the insight. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self.tv reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tv setEditing:editing animated:YES];
}
```